# Cropped PDF file in LaTeX as an output

Tags: pdf, latex, pdflatex

I am having a problem in producing a cropped PDF file in `LaTeX` using the `preview` package with `tightpage` option.

I want to put two independently created PDF images into one `LaTeX` file and produce a singled PDF image. My `LaTeX` file is

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,graphics]{preview}

\begin{document}
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics{fig1}\includegraphics{fig2}
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

When I run `pdflatex`, I get an empty PDf file. The `log` is given below

```
...
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
Preview: PDFoutput 1
<fig1.pdf, id=1, 297.28665pt x 190.31703pt> <use fig1.pdf> (./fig.aux) 

No pages of output.
Transcript written on fig.log.
```

What is wrong with the code. If I use an equation instead of `includegraphics` with the extra `textmath` option, I get the right output.

Any help will be appreciated

Madhur

Comment: If I however put the `includegraphics` command within two `$` so as to make an equation with the `textmath` option, it works!

Answer (score 1):

The `minimal` documentclass is often too minimal. Instead you could use the `standalone` class which will automatically produce a cropped pdf:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[active,tightpage,graphics]{preview}

\begin{document}
%\begin{centering}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\includegraphics[page=2]{example-image-duck}
%\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you need to add the `varwidth` option to be able to use equations in `standalone` document: [link 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50171/222496), [link 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622883/222496)

Comment: Also you can use `minimal` together with standalone: `\documentclass[class=minimal,varwidth]{standalone}`

Comment: @anton_rh Don't use the minimal class, it is simply too minimal and causes all kinds of hard to diagnose problems.